# Проверка и подсчёт строк выше определенной строки

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Не совсем уверен, как изложить данную задачу, но попробую.
Имею таблицу с 4 столбцами и 27 строками. В первых трех столбцах записана всего одна цифра. Строки формируют массив чисел от **1 1 1** до  **3 3 3**. Задача состоит в том, чтобы сравнить **каждую** строку в таблице со строками, которые стоят выше нее. Например на изображении сравнивается строка 2.1.2. Проверяем цифры по каждой строке, которые стоят выше. Если число меньше или равно оно помечается "зеленым". В конечном счете нужно подсчитать количество строк, у которых все три ячейки "зеленые"(В случае с 2.1.2 их 3 штуки).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может ли кто-нибудь подсказать алгоритм решение данной задача, и возможно ли такое реализовать вообще?

Comment: "алгоритм решение данной задача" написан в начале вопроса.

Comment: у меня есть приложение старое со старым кодом, но там можешь глянуть примеры работы с ячейками в excel https://github.com/AntonNikolaevmyname/AutoSertificate-.NET